# How to increase the textbox height at runtime?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I want my text box height to be increased if the text in the text box reaches the limit. In fact, if the width of the text box can accommodate up to 15 characters, then after 15 characters my textbox size should increase so that I can see both lines of the textbox. I am using multi line textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. If you use SWT.WRAP, your text will automatically continue in a new line, when you exceed the line width of the text widget. The height will however stay the same. Therefore you have to compute it in the text modify event. After you have set the new height for the text widget, you have to layout the parent, in order to compute the new positions for the text widget siblings.

```
    final Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP);
    text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false));

    Point textSize = text.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
    Rectangle textTrim = text.computeTrim(0, 0, textSize.x,
            text.getLineHeight());
    final int textPadding = textTrim.height - text.getLineHeight();

    text.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

        @Override
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
            int height = text.getLineCount() * text.getLineHeight()
                    + textPadding;
            text.setSize(text.getSize().x, height);
            // need to layout parent, in order to change position of
            // siblings
            parent.layout();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks...for the help..Previously i tried but blinking is more  while pack but now there is no blinking...